# Is this the right way of matching every English word in Vim? (Vim RegEx)

Tags: html, regex, vim

I am currently using this regex substitution string on an html, to match all English *words* in some lines and enclose them into a `<bdo dir="ltr">` tag.

The reason I need to do this is because the site has both Arabic and English characters, and the Arabic ones need to be enclosed in a `<bdo dir="rtl">` tag, since Arabic is read from right to left.

So I am using this regex substitution:

```
.,.+2s/\(\<\w*\>\)/<bdo dir="ltr">\1<\/bdo>/g
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot to ask of regex, but it's a sensible approach if you're reasonably certain that the only sequences of `\w` characters in your documents are in fact English words.  I would say try it and inspect some results and see if you get anything you don't like.